# What is the proper way to use a mapped attribute in a relationship and still allow for eager loading in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm having some trouble figuring out the right way to create a [SQL Expression mapped attribute](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapper_config.html?highlight=column_property#mapper-sql-expressions) which involves two tables.  I want to use the attribute I create in a relationship to join on third table.  I also want to avoid N+1 query problems and use eager loading.  I've attempted to do this with `column_property()` as it is my understanding that I can't create a relationship with an `@hybrid_property` or use it for eager loading *(please correct me if I'm wrong)*.

I have a fairly complicated set of models, but I have tried to minimize the code to just what would be needed to describe this question.

Below on `Network` I create the attributes `fqdn` and `d_fqdn`.  `fqdn` is created using a selector and `d_fqdn` is done seemingly by magic as it's not clear to me how sqlalchemy knows how to concatenate the `network.name` and `domain.name` columns properly.  This is where I need some help.  My gut feeling is that I'm doing something wrong here even though it mostly works.

The point of all this is to create a fully qualified domain name attribute on `Network` that I can use to build a relationship with `DNSRecord`.  In turn that relationship should allow me to eagerly load the `DNSRecords` using `joinedload('dns_records')`.  I don't have any database foreign keys between `Network` and `DNSRecord`, just the implied relationship that `Network.fqdn == DNSRecord.owner` or `Network.fqdn == DNSRecord.target`.

Trying to create this implied relationship with the selector based `Network.fqdn` does not seem to work.  At least I can't get it to work correctly.

However, using `Network.d_fqdn` does allow me to create the relationship and works almost as expected.  I can easily eagerly load `DNSRecords` using a query like `session.query(Network).options(joinedload('dns_records'))` without having to do N+1 queries.

I say using `Network.d_fqdn` almost works because it appears that queries which eager load `Network` seem to multiply their results by the number of rows in the `domain` table.

For example: `session.query(PhysicalSite).options(joinedload('networks')).all()` will add `FROM domain, physical_site` to the SQL query when you really only want `FROM physical_site`.

Does anyone know the right way to setup the relationship between `Network` and `DNSRecord` using `fqdn` instead of `d_fqdn`?  Or perhaps using something else entirely?  Any help would be appreciated.

```python
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import (backref, remote, foreign, joinedload, relationship,
                            column_property, with_polymorphic, sessionmaker)
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///foo.db', echo=True)

Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata

class Domain(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'domain'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(256), nullable=False, unique=True)
    networks = relationship('Network',
                            cascade="all,delete,delete-orphan",
                            foreign_keys="[Network.domain_id]")
    def __str__(self):
        return name
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Domain({})".format(self.name)

# This association table is needed for many to many relationship with
# Domains and PhysicalSites
domain_physical_site_association_table = Table(
    'domain_physical_site', metadata,
    Column('domain_id', Integer, ForeignKey('domain.id')),
    Column('physical_site_id', Integer, ForeignKey('physical_site.id')))

class PhysicalSite(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'physical_site'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(256), nullable=False)
    code = Column(String(256), nullable=False)
    domains = relationship(
        'Domain',
        secondary=domain_physical_site_association_table,
        cascade="all,delete",
        backref="physical_sites")
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}:{}".format(self.name, self.code)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "PhysicalSite({})".format(self.code)

# This association table is needed for many to many relationship with
# Networks and PhysicalSites
network_physical_site_association_table = Table(
        'network_physical_site', metadata,
        Column('network_id', Integer, ForeignKey('network.id')),
        Column('physical_site_id', Integer, ForeignKey('physical_site.id')))

class Network(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'network'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    domain_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('domain.id'))

    domain = relationship('Domain', foreign_keys="[Network.domain_id]")
    physical_sites = relationship('PhysicalSite',
            secondary=network_physical_site_association_table,
            cascade="all,delete",
            backref="networks")
    # foo-net.example.com.
    fqdn = column_property(
        (select([name + '.' + Domain.name + '.'])
         .where(Domain.id == domain_id)
         .correlate_except(Domain))
    )
    # This works, but causes an additional from clause on the 'domain' table
    # which effectively multiplies all my results by the length of the
    # domain table
    d_fqdn = column_property(name + "." + Domain.name + ".")
    dns_records = relationship('DNSRecord',
        primaryjoin="or_(\
            remote(DNSRecord.target) == foreign(Network.d_fqdn),\
            remote(DNSRecord.owner) == foreign(Network.d_fqdn))",
        uselist=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.fqdn
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Network({})".format(self.fqdn)

class DNSRecord(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dns_record'
    rr_type = Column(String(256), nullable=False, index=True)
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': rr_type, 'with_polymorphic': '*'}
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    rr_class = Column(String(256), nullable=False, default='IN')
    owner = Column(String(256), nullable=False, index=True)
    target = Column(String(256), nullable=True, index=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} IN {} {}".format(self.owner, self.rr_type, self.target)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "DNSRecord({})".format(self.rr_type)

class DNSRecordA(DNSRecord):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'A'}
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} IN A {}".format(self.owner, self.target)

class DNSRecordPTR(DNSRecord):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'PTR'}
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} IN PTR {}".format(self.owner, self.target)

Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)
session = Session()
```

Also I'll note that I'm using sqlalchemy 0.9.3 and python 2.7.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so from a relational design point of view this is a *terrible* way to do things.  let's just focus on network/domain/dnsrecord.   A very easy way to do this would be that DNSRecord has a simple foreign key to network; in this case dnsrecord.owner_network_id and dnsrecord.target_network_id.  The string form of dnsrecord.owner and dnsrecord.target would be just "self.network.name + "." self.network.domain.name + "."".  if you're navigating from Network to dns_records, those Network and Domain objects are already present in the identity map, so accessors like "self.network" and "self.network.domain" are free.

That is, relational design is very much about storing a particular piece of information only once.

so with the caveat that **this design is terrible and unnecessary**, to make it work as is we will refer to [relationship to non primary mapper](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#relationship-to-non-primary-mapper) which can pretty much do anything, and here it is:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, and_, or_
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, relationship, Session, joinedload, foreign

Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata

class Domain(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'domain'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    networks = relationship('Network', backref="domain")

class Network(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'network'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    domain_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('domain.id'))

    @property
    def fqdn(self):
        return self.name + "." + self.domain.name + "."

class DNSRecord(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dns_record'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    owner = Column(String)
    target = Column(String)


fqdn_network = select([DNSRecord, Domain.id.label('domain_id'), Domain.name.label('domain_name')]).alias()

d_fqdn = Network.name + "." + fqdn_network.c.domain_name + "."

dns_alt = mapper(DNSRecord, fqdn_network, non_primary=True)
Network.dns_records = relationship(dns_alt, primaryjoin=
                            and_(
                                Network.domain_id == foreign(fqdn_network.c.domain_id),
                                or_(
                                    fqdn_network.c.target == d_fqdn,
                                    fqdn_network.c.owner == d_fqdn
                                )
                            ),
                            viewonly=True
                        )

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///', echo='debug')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session = Session(engine)

session.add_all([
    DNSRecord(owner="apple.foo.com."),
    DNSRecord(target="peach.foo.com."),
    DNSRecord(owner="banana.foo.com."),
    DNSRecord(target="banana.foo.com."),
    DNSRecord(owner="pear.bar.com."),
    DNSRecord(owner="peach.bar.com."),

    Domain(name="foo.com", networks=[
            Network(name="apple"),
            Network(name="peach"),
            Network(name="banana"),
    ]),
    Domain(name="bar.com", networks=[
            Network(name="pear"),
            Network(name="peach"),
    ])
])
session.commit()

for network in session.query(Network).options(joinedload(Network.dns_records)):
    for dns in network.dns_records:
        print dns.owner, dns.target, network.fqdn
        assert dns.owner == network.fqdn or dns.target == network.fqdn
```

A particularly nasty aspect of this is that you necessarily have the cartesian product occurring within a subquery:

```
SELECT network.id AS network_id, network.name AS network_name, network.domain_id AS network_domain_id, anon_1.id AS anon_1_id, anon_1.owner AS anon_1_owner, anon_1.target AS anon_1_target, anon_1.domain_id AS anon_1_domain_id, anon_1.domain_name AS anon_1_domain_name 

FROM network 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT dns_record.id AS id, dns_record.owner AS owner, dns_record.target AS target, 
         domain.id AS domain_id, domain.name AS domain_name 
         FROM dns_record, domain) AS anon_1 
    ON network.domain_id = anon_1.domain_id AND (anon_1.target = network.name || ? || anon_1.domain_name || ? OR anon_1.owner = network.name || ? || anon_1.domain_name || ?)
```

that's because we can't join dns_record to domain directly, unless we joined on something like the string split of DNSRecord.target/DNSRecord.owner or the substring, which also wouldn't perform very well.   We have to pull in the "network" side of things in order to figure out how dns_record and domain can be joined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Normally I would not favor this approach, as you succinctly put it "terrible", but due to other factors not described here this may actually be viable for my particular case. i.e. I may not be able to add dns_record.owner_network_id/target_network_id.

Comment: one other thing to note is that this doesn't allow for polymorphism without additional code, so I guess I need to follow http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/inheritance.html?highlight=polymorphic#using-relationships-with-inheritance for that part.  Getting this into a more straightforward join() on ids setup is looking better and better by the moment.